# Goodbye @lélecteur

Tags: discussion

Just noticed that this user deleted their account few hours ago. It is unfortunate that we didn't throw a farewell party before it happened :'((

Comment: Anyone know why? I was looking forward to having them back after the year's suspension (still no idea what that was about) . A few helpful comments and then this bombshell :(

Comment: One really annoying thing about this is that you get used to seeing names that you trust on answers. If I saw an answer from l'electeur I could be pretty sure it was going to be high quality and accurate. I have no idea about the answers of user4032. Although, considering my username, I guess I can't complain :)

Comment: Same here, when I think of most active and best users in this site, native speakers naruto and Chocolate pops in mind. lol

Comment: Indeed, though there are a quite a few more excellent contributors. I'm not going to name names.

Comment: How unfortunate!  I also had no idea that they'd been suspended, nor why.  The SE functionality that removes user names is really not helpful to the site -- even if a user is deactivated, the user name is still helpful to site readers.  The fact that we lose not just @lélecteur's future contributions, but also effectively their past contributions, is quite a blow...

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Ditto. I've just become accustomed to associating user1478 on Japanese SE and user230 on ELL with snail. Now here's another one I have to make sure I know.

Comment: I salute their contributions, but I would refrain from titling this post "Rest in peace", since it usually indicates a more permanent retirement...

Comment: @jogloran I originally wanted to say "RIP @lélecteur" but it didn't reach the minimum character count. I'm not sure how to make a better title...

Comment: "Goodbye to l'électeur"? "l'électeur, you will be missed"? Many, many others that don't imply the poster's demise 

Comment: I received a lump sum of positive reps yesterday, because a "user" has been deleted and his unfair down votes were cancelled :) Quick calculation revealed that this user was down voting just about every single answer I posted :) :)

Comment: @dungariqn FWIW I *lost* 494 rep from it, so it’s not like he was downvoting everyone.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed it was him until today... For the record, I lost some reps from this (1890 lost from cancelled upvotes; 342 gained from cancelled downvotes; -1548 total), but since he was one of the most aggressive voters (in both directions), I had thought the change would be much bigger.

Comment: 4400 loss for me. suspect he was rather more lenient on question askers than answerers.

Comment: To be honest I'd delete my account just for this SE if I could. Almost all of downvoters doesn't give any reasons to do so, unlike any other SE(of course aside from obvious reason), which is, I think, seriously bad attitude. Plus some of the community members (I won't list names!) are being (a little bit) toxic-ish to newcomer/(kind of) bad questioner. I'm not saying that I've never said anything bad to some other users, but this SE is not a good place to stay, honestly. Just for the record I've lost 14 reps (+16, -30; which means 8 Dv 3 Uv) in total. He didn't told me any reasons to DV me :)

Comment: Relevant to my comment: [Please explain downvotes](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/731/please-explain-downvotes). At least comment before downvoting, is it that hard for ya?

Comment: @Skye-AT Just ignore them, who cares about internet points anyway.

Comment: @Skye-AT I went through your posts and only found a single one with a negative score. I left a comment there explaining why it was likely downvoted. Hope that helps.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie , well then I guess the almost only downvoter was him I guess? I do remember that I had at least 5 posts with negative score. Anyway, thanks for your input, but I am currently have no motivations to fix it(so instead I'm going to delete that; it has better answer anyway.) I do agree on what you wrote though; I was relatively new at that time, so instead of explaining everything I just went for "it's just like that". That's my bad for that, I'll make sure I won't do that in future.

Comment: And @JimmyYang , yes I'm always ignoring it, unless it's not serial-downvote that comes without reason. According to my reputation page the culprit was him since I am currently only has 3 or so downvotes that is in effect (checked with vote counts.) It happened thrice in a month, ultimately that made me taking a break for this SE. Don't take me wrong, I'm not saying that he was a bad guy, I actually respect him. He had very good insight, skills, and such that's needed for this SE. Sorry to hear that he left this SE.

Comment: Perhaps anyone might want to check it: [Why is the Japanese Language Stack Exchange site so negative?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1343/why-is-the-japanese-language-stack-exchange-site-so-negative).

Comment: I had a net loss of 36 points, as lélecteur had evidently upvoted me 4 times and downvoted me 2 times. I take this as clear evidence that lélecteur used a sliding scale (i.e., was more critical of those with more expertise and more lenient with those, like me, whose knowledge is very limited). I have certainly learned a great deal from lélecteur's contributions to the site, and I'll miss them.

Comment: Is there anyone who was downvoted by him more times than me (171 times)? :D @Skye-AT I'm pretty certain that most silent downvotes on this site were by him. Actually, serial silent downvoting was the very reason he had his account suspended for the second time. I think this won't happen again.

Comment: I honestly felt like I got way more downvotes from him than I actually ended up getting (it looks like I was downvoted 10 times and upvoted 14 times). I suppose downvotes just stick in your mind longer.

Comment: @naruto -- He'd dinged me with 52 downvotes in total, I think none of those had any comment from him.  But 171 downvotes!  That's a heck of a negative reputation effect from one user.  Easily offset by your high volume of other positively-scoring posts, but still, not cool.  Interesting the impact one user can make.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi How exactly is downvoting posts you think are low quality "not cool"? That is literally why the functionality exists. It's fine for the community to encourage leaving comments, but the scoring system here is the one thing that separates this site from some useless bulletin board style forum, so it's *not* fine for the community to complete vilify downvotes. It's natural for one of the (former) best answerers on the site to have a strong opinion about what's good/bad, and he chose to act on it. (Serial downvoting  regardless of post quality is obviously different & unacceptable.)

Comment: I find myself in complete agreement with @DariusJahandarie And IMHO the downvoting function actually keeps the SE ecosystem balanced, relatively objective, sustainable, and most importantly self-moderating. Not that I consider it's fair at all for extremely helpful contributors like naruto and Eiríkr Útlendi (from both of whom I have learned a great deal) to be on the receiving end of _that many downvotes_. It's beyond me how that could've happened, but the possibility of that happening _is part and parcel of our ecosystem._

Comment: @EddieKal For example, naruto has 5011 answers on the site. l'électeur's 171 downvotes is 3.4% of his answers. Now I've never downvoted any of naruto's answers, but mostly because I don't feel particular qualified to even have a strong negative opinion on the majority of them. I can only upvote when it aligns with my beliefs and seems useful and clear. l'électeur is a native speaker, (I believe) an older one with professional experience in the language, generally an opinionated fellow, and was very active on the site, so it's unsurprising to me he might downvote a small percentage of them.

Comment: I know that getting downvotes does not feel good, and it's hard to have a good community if a lot of people feel bad. But I think there is simply too much obsession on downvotes here. If this is the only experience some people have of getting negative feedback in their entire lives then maybe it feels rough to them, but a couple downvotes here and there should mean nothing if you're receiving tens-of-thousands of cumulative upvotes. There's always going to be someone who disagrees with a large enough community.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie, the "not cool" that I was referring to was a combination of the sheer volume of downvotes from one user, combined with a lack of any comment from that user, despite their clearly having the expertise required to articulate useful feedback.  That reads to me as petty and punitive, rather than good faith.  It's not the existence of the downvotes themselves -- it's the volume, and the unhelpfulness, in the case of this specific user.

Comment: If a downvote is motivated by an honest desire to improve the site, then ideally that downvote is 1) accompanied by a comment to the poster on how to improve their post, either added by the downvoter themselves or by someone else; or 2) under a question that has multiple answers, and the downvote has the effect of pushing incorrect information down in the order of display on the page.  Even for #2 above, a comment explaining what is incorrect is helpful to everyone.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi Is downvoting 3.4% of someone’s answers really excessive? BTW, I agree leaving a comment is nice but I don’t think it should be mandated (either by technology or by norms; and talking cr*p about someone’s voting habits after they left seems like trying to aggressively establish such a norm to me). I largely agree with the top-rated answer on this highly relevant SE meta post, please consider reading: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325416/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi I can't help but feel that that standard for "helpfulness" is asking just a tad too much. We can't reasonably demand that all well-meaning members of the community all conform to uniform standards of niceness that includes such things as "if you downvote, you better leave a comment telling us why." It is neither practical in _any_ online community in general nor part of the design of SE per se. I understand your argument that such a high volume of unexplained downvotes are unhelpful to the community and the posters. But I'd like to discuss an instance where the opposite happened

Comment: (cont'd) Just for the record, this doesn't counter your opinion that l'électeur's actions were "uncool" and "unhelpful". On the contrary, it may help your argument. I saw a multi-upvoted answer with an comment under it from l'électeur: "Why so many upvotes here?" We can all agree it wasn't a nice gesture. But the answer wasn't downvoted (this was before l'électeur deleted his account). So he apparently thought the answer was lacking in some regard and chose to leave a comment expressing that in a blunt and even jarring way, but he didn't downvote it.

Comment: (cont'd) That just goes to show that he was a bit of a colorful character with a strong and _different_ personality. No, he wasn't nice per se; (because) he was different. Ofc, it would've been nice had he been nicer. But we just can't ask that of every member of the community. From my observation, we have generous upvoters in the community; we have people who always give new askers an encouraging thumbs-up; but OTOH we also got many users who could be nicer in some ways. They may not mass-dv like l'électeur did, but some things are on the same level of "unhelpfulness" as silent dv.

Comment: l'électeur wasn't the only one. We have other users, very knowledgeable, massively helpful users who could be nicer in some aspects of their contributions. We have quite a few contributors with loads of distinct personality. But I just don't think crucifying l'électeur on his dv is fair, because he was (and still is) enormously and lastingly helpful. "He should've at least left a comment" just sounds like asking a tad too much. If you ask em, I'd like to ask a LOT of askers to be sure to upvote and accept good answers. That'd, IMHO, be a bigger leap towards making community members feel good.

Comment: His downvotes, albeit silent, did make some sense to me for a long time. Some of his downvotes did help me to think again and improve my answer even if they were due to minor English mistakes as a nonnative speaker. However, his downvotes became less and less helpful to me in the last few years. As my knowledge of Japanese and English increased, his downvote rate on my answers kept going up (over 50% in the worst times), to the point where I finally gave up and started to regard his downvotes as negligible noise. Still, I did not complain loudly.

Comment: (continued) But In 2019 (IIRC), he even started searching for my old posts and downvote precisely 4 of them every day, which was clearly against the rule (he didn't downvote more than 4 answers a day to evade the automatic correction mechanism). IMO, it was when he crossed the red line. He had been "biased" to say the least, but at this point, it became undeniable that he abused the voting system to harass certain users he personally disliked. I still strongly believe his overall contributions easily outweigh the downside, but his voting behavior was not something I can agree with.

Comment: ... And that is also my experience, except he only DV'd me twice in a day (and that happened thrice in a month). I am guessing it's just minor issues with Japanese/English since I've not talked (or even interacted) him that much, though it's (almost) same. And... @EddieKal - Tad too much? Is it? I believe most of downvotes has a reason to do so; The downvoter must have thought the answer has something bad in it, so they've choosed to downvote. Is outputting that into a comment that hard for him, or everybody? I don't think so, since it's not hard to find that kind of behaviour outside JLSE.

Comment: Of course, he is not the only one to blame. But when a number of users are reporting it, it's clear that he had a problem. Of course, Stackexchange does not recommend such behavior (in fact, he has been suspended twice, it seems). I respect his knowledge and skills, but I don't think this kind of behavior is commendable.

Comment: @naruto That kind of behavior _is_ utterly unacceptable. I am with you there. And being very familiar with snail's moderation style, I also have complete faith in the moderation team's handling of that incident, and I trust that the problem had been communicated to him and he had been asked to stop prior to handing out a year-long suspension, but what might've led to him running amok with dv still seems unfathomable. That said, whatever the reason might've been, holding grudges and acting upon grudges with a passion are unacceptable.

Comment: @Skye-AT Many generous upvoters/well respected contributors downvote posts without saying anything right then and there. snail, a widely respected ex-mod on ELL and Japanese, once explained in ELL's public chat room why many years before she'd downvoted an ELU answer claiming "ofc English has a future tense." It was only years after she cast her downvote that she gave some sort of explanation, and not even to the answerer. That ELU answer scored 100+, IIRC. But as a linguist, snail knew it was wrong and why it was wrong; she just chose to keep silent. I've been silently dv-ed by her too.

Comment: Some seem to think this is an issue particular to JSE or somehow there's more negativity here. I totally disagree. I discussed this with snail in private. I remember saying many ELL and ELU users seemed nitpicky and arrogant, and "I've never seen such things on Japanese SE or other sites." This is sort of a "grass greener on the other side of the fence" situation. But having been around for a while now, I can say upvoters here do seem more generous. As naruto explained, those suspensions had specific reasons. Comment-less dv shouldn't be confused with targeted dv. Completely separate matters.

Comment: @EddieKal Snailplane, while she may have done some silent DV, I remember that she usually gave reasons for the DV. If she silent-DV'd some users continuously like lélecteur did, then I'd have to agree with you, but she did not. It's a totally different case, at least from my perspective. Please note that I did not say you must provide a reason for your DV - just that it is better if you provided a reason, as a learning opportunity and a guide for future answerers, and of course, future readers).

Comment: I still believe JLSE has some negative characteristics compared to other SEs. Since I'm not active at ELU / ELL, I don't know about those communities, but in the communities that I participate in (Arqade and Ask different) there haven't been any issues like this (at least for an year). JLSE, however, had twice in an year - that is, what I call negativity. I don't know if it's just timing, but still, it is not healthy for a community to have influential users choosing to leave, no matter the reason.

Comment: Probably there are more archive in this community comparing to other site. So, it's easy for a long term or knowledgeable users to find errors. Probably l'electurer may have been allowing some users to mimic his down-vote habit if someone sees his comments. Someone may feel it's also okay for me to downvote like him unconsciously because it seems norm of this site.

Comment: It is natural for Naruto to get pissed off by his incessant downvoting for years since Naruto cannot fix any errors of his answers to elaborate on as an expert here. So, l’electuer should show burden of proof as an expert to Naruto’ if what he has done is so important.

Comment: I didn't read the whole thread here, but there is another solution that would completely remove the effect of one serial and silent downvoter -- other people can try and UPVOTE answers more often when they think that it is correct. I often see questions where the answer is correct, accepted and only have one upvote, meaning that only OP bothered evaluating the answer...